# What am I doing wrong with this Cython code?

Tags: numpy, cython

Can you please critique this piece of code that I have?

For context, I am trying to learn Cython and see how it can serve a future use case where I would like to integrate C and Python.

This "exercise" code works like this:

1. I read from a file a long list of 3d coordinates describing two points at timesteps
2. I calculate the Euclidean distance between the two points at each time step and report it as a numpy array

I am using Pure Python mode of Cython.

```
# computer.py

import cython
# from cython.cimports.cpython import array
# import array
import numpy as np

if cython.compiled:
    print("Yep, I'm compiled.")
    from cython.cimports.libc.math import sqrt

else:
    print("Just a lowly interpreted script.")
    from math import sqrt


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cfunc
def compute_distance_cy(x1: cython.float, y1: cython.float, z1: cython.float,
                        x2: cython.float, y2: cython.float, z2: cython.float):

    return sqrt(sum(((x1 - x2) ** 2.0, (y1 - y2) ** 2.0, (z1 - z2) ** 2.0)))


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.ccall
def compute_distances_pure(points: cython.double[:, :]):

    # get the maximum dimensions of the array
    x_max: cython.size_t = points.shape[0]
    y_max: cython.size_t = points.shape[1]

    # create memoryviews of the single points
    view2d: cython.double[:, :] = points
    view1d: cython.double[:]

    # create memoryviews of the results
    result = np.zeros(x_max, dtype=np.double)
    result2dview: cython.double[:] = result

    # access the memoryview by way of our constrained indexes
    x: cython.size_t
    for x in range(x_max):
        view1d = view2d[x, :]
        result2dview[x] = compute_distance_cy(
            view1d[0], view1d[1], view1d[2], view1d[3], view1d[4], view1d[5])

    return result
```

This is called from:

```
...

def pure_python_mode(points):
    return computer.compute_distances_pure(points)

def do_it_in_numpy(points):
    return np.sqrt((points[:, 0] - points[:, 3])**2 +
                   (points[:, 1] - points[:, 4])**2 +
                   (points[:, 2] - points[:, 5])**2)


points_ndarray = np.array(points_list, dtype=np.double)
points_distance_array_from_cython = pure_python_mode(points_ndarray)
points_distance_array_from_numpy = do_it_in_numpy(points_ndarray)
```

I time the two approaches with a simple wrapper.
At this point I was able to achieve:

```
Function pure_python_mode Took 0.0439 seconds
Function do_it_in_numpy Took 0.0183 seconds
```

I am generally 4x-8x worse in Cython as in Numpy. That's plenty acceptable for my use cases but I would like to know if somebody could point out if I am doing something wrong or if this is as good as it gets here.

Comment: 1. Consider using `**2` instead of `** 2.0`. The former should be replaced with `x*x` while the later might use the slow `pow` math call doing expensive floating-point log/exp calls. 2. the Cython code is not SIMD friendly while the Numpy code is although the Numpy code creates expensive temporary arrays. It is certainly the main source of the slow-down. 3. I am not sure `sum` is efficiently implemented in Cython. What about using just a `+` (simpler, possibly faster, and easier to read IMO). 4. The Numpy code use double precision while Cython do simple precision and conversions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general tip cython has an "annotate" option, if you compile with that it will show you which lines are likely the issue (i.e. still using python rather than c) and give you a good idea why.

For example if you are biulding via setup.py you can enable this by changing `cythonize("your_file.pyx")` to `cythonize("your_file.pyx", annotate=True)`.

some specific notes:

### `compute_distance_cy`:

- `(x1-x2)**2.0` etc. are done using python rules rather than c, here just square manually, generally consider importing math functions from c in the same way you have for `sqrt`
- `sum(...)` is relatively expensive, here can just use `+`, for larger arrays consider a loop
- you probably want `cython.double` rather than `cython.float` (otherwise you are loosing half your accuracy
- you want to add a return type
- `boundscheck` and `wraparound` are unnecessary (you are not doing any indexing in this function)

combining these you function could look like this:

```py
@cython.cfunc
def compute_distance_cy(x1: cython.double, y1: cython.double, z1: cython.double, x2: cython.double, y2: cython.double, z2: cython.double) -> cython.double:
    dx: cython.double = x1 - x2
    dy: cython.double = y1 - y2
    dz: cython.double = z1 - z2
    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz)
```

### `compute_distances_pure`

- some of your views are unnecessary e.g. `view2d` - `points` is already the type you want, so just use that directly
- it is more expensive to index into views of views than directly (i.e. when you do `view1d[0]` that's slower than just `view2d[x,0]`), avoid this if possible

```py
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.ccall
def compute_distances_pure(points: cython.double[:, :]) -> cython.double[:]:
    x_max: cython.size_t = points.shape[0]
    result : cython.double[:] = np.zeros(x_max, dtype=np.double)

    x: cython.size_t
    for x in range(x_max):
        result[x] = d3(points[x, 0], points[x, 1], points[x, 2], points[x, 3], points[x, 4], points[x, 5])

Simplifying your second function could look something like:

    return result
```

### Result

combining these ideas i get a ~75x speedup over the original cython version